# Problem with versioning on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, versioning

I have the problem of Versioning on Sharepoint Online.

When I set limits of the version it doesn't allow me to delete those versions. A lot of workers edit this document library and its product a lot of versions. But I want for example leave only 8 of them.

[image]

[image]
And the Sharepoint reach 9 Versions and more. I want to protect disc space.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Or an unusual generosity from SPOnline if they don't count that against your storage quota.

Comment: How could I fix this ?

Comment: Contact support

Comment: Have you changed the number after the 9 versions was created? SharePoint deletes old files only if a new version is added, so simply reduce the number, does not delete a old version.